# getting null in "selectId(infoId)" in gmap-v3-geofence.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geofencing

```
Geofence.prototype.setInfo = function(polygon, infoId) 
{
    selectId(polygon).value = getCoordinatesString(polygon);
}
```

> > gmap-v3-geofence.js:208 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at Geofence.setInfo (gmap-v3-geofence.js:208) at
> >     drawPolygon (geofencing.js:27) at geofencing.js:17

Need some serious Help. I am using the following code from Github. [Click Here](https://github.com/sujancse/google-map-geofence)

Comment: When are you getting this error?

Comment: on page load, and actually I want if I click inside the selected area, it'll give me lat, lng of clicked area.

Comment: Can you please post your full code or a jsfiddle? As far as I can see, the demo works without problem https://sujancse.github.io/geofence/

Comment: thanks @evan. I have changed the code, use google polygon map and make a change in it to fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Right! So I understand that you've solved this yourself now? If so feel free to answer your own question for the community's sake. If you still have this issue then please share your modified code so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was to put a section on a Google Map, which I can drag and resize as well, so I use the following code and got my required result:

```
<script>
// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
  // When the user clicks on the polygon an info window opens, showing
  // information about the polygon's coordinates.
  var map;
  var infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 31.448809299757535, lng: -99.08335389822349},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
    var triangleCoords = [
        {lat: 31.422875949492543, lng: -99.89672607421875},
        {lat: 31.03122750234828, lng: -98.66225048828124},
        {lat: 32.02807714324144, lng: -98.65806201171876},
        {lat: 31.735314763657264, lng: -99.22246240234375}
    ];
    // Construct the polygon.
    var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: triangleCoords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true,
    });
    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
    // Add a listener for the click event.
    bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', showArrays);
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  }
  /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
  function showArrays(event) {
    // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
    // MVCArray of LatLngs.
    var vertices = this.getPath();
    var contentString = '<b><strong>Selected polygon</strong></b><br>' +
        'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
        '<br>';
    // Iterate over the vertices.
    for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
      var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
      contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
          xy.lng();
    }
    // Replace the info window's content and position.
    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
```

Before that I was using geofence-v3-map.js which is deprecated.